# Laravel Jeffrey Way Generators: "Add To" Confusion

Tags: php, laravel, way-generators

I'm following along with [Jeffrey Way's generator](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) tutorial for Laravel, and I'm a little confused by the "add to" syntax for migrations.  If I run the following command

```
php artisan generate:migration add_user_id_to_posts_table
```

I generate the following migration script

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('posts', function(Blueprint $table) {

    });
}
```

The `generate:migration` command has successfully added a call to `Schema::table` — but there's no mention of the `user_id` from the command.  Is it my responsibility to add this myself, or does the `user_id` field get added elsewhere?  If the former, what's the syntax for adding this field to a table in place?  If the later, where is "elsewhere"?

I know I can specify a list of fields when I first create the table, but I'm interested in knowing either the "Jeffrey Way way" or the "standard Laravel PHP code" way for modifying a table in place via migrations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
php artisan generate:migration add_user_id_to_posts_table --fields="user_id:integer"
```